# Is it practically feasible to implement Gtk3 API over Qt?

Tags: qt, gtk, gtk3

That might be an already well-discussed topic, yet I am having bad luck finding anything besides general "A vs B vs C ..." threads.

So, to put it straight:

1. Is it technically possible in general, or Qt and Gtk3 event-loops and objects hierarchies are not that easy to map onto each other?
2. "Environmental" limitations, eg. interoperation with various auxiliary libraries like glib, pango, cairo, etc.
3. Could the maintenance process be semi-automatic? Would it require tremendous amount of human work?
4. ... (some other considerations, that makes task non-viable/non-achievable?)

Thanks!

P.S. Just to clarify, **1.** is not about C and C++ difference or such, but rather a question from an architectural standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is practically feasible if you, both.

1. Have experts who have or can be paid to develop first-hand familiarity with both Qt's and GTK 3's internals.
2. Have a ton of money to burn for no good reason. You're thinking of thousands of hours of work and for what?

If you throw enough money and manpower at such a problem, you will get the results you wish. So, the question doesn't make much sense as stated. From an architectural standpoint, adapting GTK3 interfaces to ride on top of Qt is simply a matter of effort. Nothing in this area is impossible.

Why would you do such a thing is beyond me, but oh well.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am interested in is exactly architectural insight and practical limitations, rather than bunch of vague "blah-blah tons of money blah-blah". Is it viable as OSS initiative, is that worth it? To answer those questions, it is neccessary to understand limitations at first place.

Comment: @XPinguin If your goal is to port something to Qt, just do that. Develop the tools that use the AST from a C/C++ parser to rewrite most of Gtk into Qt, do the rest manually. That's the way to go. Gtk on top of Qt is a lost cause. Your question puts the cart in front of the horse. Your goal is to port Gtk3 apps to Qt. You ask what it takes for Solution X to work, without asking if that solution even makes any sense. Talk of your underlying problem.

Comment: @XPinguin There are absolutely no limitations other than manpower. Yes, you can develop a Gtk3 front-end on top of Qt. It's not worth doing. There's nothing architecturally that could ever prevent you from doing that. I've had a project where a chunk of winapi was reimplemented on top of Qt, just to see if a legacy MFC (!!) app could be quickly ported to an embedded system. I don't see how Gtk3 is any better/worse. It's just a big effort, and the added layer of indirection is unnecessary. The right thing it to automate the port.

Comment: It is not about porting any app from gtk to qt. It is about exactly what I've already stated (hope, clearly enough) in the opening question: implementing whole gtk3 api using qt as underlying engine, with subsequent maintenance (api tend to evolve). That is not my goal yet, for now I am just curious. As I was unable to find any relevant discussions on the Web, the first thing is to ask somebody who may know, before delving into depth of unknown by myself.

Comment: regarding winapi emulation over qt: for instance, wine is pretty much alive (unrelated to qt, though). The most problematic part here is about versions compatibility and HUGE pile of undocumented behaviour, as I could understand. That shouldn't be the case for gtk3 which also has problems with documentation, yet being open for semi-automatic analysis of execution branches (via symbolic execution, for instance) without much need for low-level reverse engineering (as with winapi emulation).

Comment: The big question still is: why would you ever want to do such a thing? The lack of discussions about this is because it's nuts. If you want to develop new stuff, use Qt Quick. If you want to port, port, getting help from people who know gtk and know how to port. This shim layer would not find any use - what for? Gtk is underdocumented enough that people who use it commit enough mistakes that you'd need bug-for-bug compatiblity. It'd be easier to insert a shim between Gtk and Qt to get them to coexist, and port piece-by-piece.